# SQL Query to drop constraint with space in constraint name. Example - ORD_PYMNT_DTL PK

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not sure how but somehow one of the constraint names in a table has a space in its name. When I write the below query to drop it, oracle gives me an error.

**Query -**

```
alter table ORD_DTL drop constraint ORD_PYMNT_DTL PK;
```

**Error -**

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
alter table ORD_DTL drop constraint ORD_PYMNT_DTL PK
Error report -
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: `"ORD_PYMNT_DTL PK"`

Comment: Read about quoted identifiers [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA); rule 7 is particularly relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose it into double quotes:

```
alter table ORD_DTL drop constraint "ORD_PYMNT_DTL PK";
```